# Convergence of Talyor series of a real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Hi everyone: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two real analytic functions on a bounded domain $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we have 
$$0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$$ on $D$. Suppose the Taylor series associated to $g$ about $x_{0}$ is convergent for $|x-x_{0}|<r$. Can we conclude that the Taylor series associated to $f$ about the same point is also convergent on $|x-x_{0}|<r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try $n=1$, $x_0 = 0$, $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ and $g(x) = 1$.